# Transform scale on card flip

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

How do I use a `transform:scale()` on a card flip animation in CSS? When I put a `transform:scale(0.75);` on `.container` and hover to flip the card, the `transform` goes away?

Please use Chrome or Safari to see the issue.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400i,700,700i,900,900i');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i');

html, body { 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  background-color:#eaeaea;}

.container {
  width:900px;
  height:550px;
  background-color:white;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;}

.right-div {
  width:540px;
  height:550px;
  background-image:url();
  transform:scale(1);
  background-position: -170px 0px; 
  background-size:cover;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;}

.left-div {
  width:323px;
  height:550px;
  background-color:white;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;}

.content-name {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #7E7E7E;    
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top:160px;
    margin-left:40px;}

.content-title {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    font-size: 44px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2C2C2C;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:40px;}

.content-description {
    margin-top: -20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #7e7e7e;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin-left:40px;}

.content-link {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:20px;
    color: #2C2C2C;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left:40px;}





/*Flip*/

.flip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}

.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 900px;
    height: 550px;}

.flipper {
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;}

.front, .back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;}

.front {
  z-index: 2;}

.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background: white;}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-div">
      <p class="content-name">title</p>
      <p class="content-title">name</p>
    <p class="content-description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus <br/> error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    <a href="#" class="content-link">Link</a>
  </div>
  <div class="right-div">
  </div>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      :p
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this may be a good workaround for you, but you can try to set `transform: scale(0.75)` to `.front` and `.back` classes instead of `.container`.

```
.front {
  transform: scale(0.75);
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(0.75);
}
```

Comment: are you sure? I tried it on jsfiddle and works fine, both side are scaled (on Chrome)

Answer (score 2):

The back side of the card should have its own 180-degree transform on it. Since it is the back, it is already flipped 180 degrees. For me in Firefox 60, this still works properly even if `scale(0.75)` is applied to `.container`. In other words, I was not able to reproduce the problem you stated, but I did notice that your card wasn't behaving like a card.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400i,700,700i,900,900i');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i');
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.container {
  width: 900px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transform: scale(0.75);
}

.right-div {
  width: 540px;
  height: 550px;
  background-image: url();
  transform: scale(1);
  background-position: -170px 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.left-div {
  width: 323px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.content-name {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #7E7E7E;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 160px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.content-title {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-size: 44px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #2C2C2C;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.content-description {
  margin-top: -20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #7e7e7e;
  line-height: 22px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.content-link {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #2C2C2C;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 40px;
}


/*Flip*/

.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  backface-visibility: visible;
}

.flip-container:hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  width: 900px;
  height: 550px;
}

.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.front,
.back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.front {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: white;
}

.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: red;

  /* this is the line you were missing */
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="left-div">
          <p class="content-name">title</p>
          <p class="content-title">name</p>
          <p class="content-description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus <br/> error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
          <a href="#" class="content-link">Link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="right-div">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      :p
      <h1> you have to put the snippet in fullscreen mode because this card is really big </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```